# Display the power of a requested (integer) number in C language

Tags: c, math

The exercise I am trying to do is to display the power of an integer number requested from the user.

I don't understand why it displays 1 instead of the number requested by the user (the power).

Here is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double x, carre, cube,resp;
    int p, tmp;
    
    printf("Enter a number : ");
    scanf("%lg", &x);
    printf("Enter a power : ");
    scanf("%d",&p);

    carre = x * x;
    cube = x * carre;
    resp = 0;
    tmp = x;
    while (p > 1){ 
        resp = tmp*x;
        p = p-1;
        tmp = resp;
    }
    
    printf("%g ^ %d = %lg\n", x, 0, 1.0);
    printf("%g ^ %d = %lg\n", x, 1, x);
    printf("%g ^ %d = %lg\n", x, 2, carre);
    printf("%g ^ %d = %lg\n", x, 3, cube);
    printf("%g ^ %d = %lg\n", x, p, resp); # it display 1 instead of the requested number (p)

    return 0;
}
```

For my example I choose 2 as number and 5 for the power

[my example compiled with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJATj.png)

I tried the source code and I asked the user to enter a number and a power, but the display shows 1 instead of the value of p which is 5 in my example (see the picture)

Comment: Your loop decrements it until it hits 1.

Comment: What do you think is the value of `p` after the `while (p > 1)` loop?

Comment: Note: `%lg` is the same as `%g` in printf format. Choose one.

Comment: Besides the problem stated in the question, the code will not calculate the correct result for `p=0` or `p=1`. And: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 3):

In this loop:

```
while (p > 1){ 
    resp = tmp*x;
    p = p-1;
    tmp = resp;
}
```

You are decrementing `p` on each time around the loop (iteration). The loop only ends when `p == 1`

So when you print `p` after the loop it is always going to be `1`.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you change your p in this line `p = p-1;`

Try to add a variable that holds your old value p like:

```
// Online C++ compiler to run C++ program online
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    double x, carre, cube,resp;
    int p, tmp, oldP;
    
    printf("Enter a number : ");
    scanf("%lg", &x);
    printf("Enter a power : ");
    scanf("%d",&p);
    
    oldP = p;
    carre = x * x;
    cube = x * carre;
    resp = 0;
    tmp = x;
    
    while (p > 1){ 
        resp = tmp*x;
        p = p-1;
        tmp = resp;
    }
    
    printf("%g ^ %d = %lg\n", x, 0, 1.0);
    printf("%g ^ %d = %lg\n", x, 1, x);
    printf("%g ^ %d = %lg\n", x, 2, carre);
    printf("%g ^ %d = %lg\n", x, 3, cube);
    printf("%g ^ %d = %lg\n", x, oldP, resp); 

    return 0;
}
```